# Stream network problem on php5.6-fpm with ftp_put()

Tags: php, apache, ftp, fastcgi

i'm going mad with this php script: before switching to php5.6-fpm it always worked (before that i used apache2 mod_php), now, when i upload a file and set up the ftp connection to the other server in order to save it, i get this error:

**Warning:** ftp_put(): Failure reading network stream

The script is very simple:

```
<?php

$remotePath  = '/httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8/8/';
$newFileName = time() . '.png';

$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect( 'example.com', 21 );

ftp_login( $ftp, 'username', 'password' );

ftp_pasv( $ftp, true );

ftp_put( $ftp, $remotePath . $newFileName, $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );

ftp_close( $ftp );
```

I've enabled the logs on the target server and this is the result of the operation:

```
CONNECT: Client 
FTP response: Client  "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
FTP command: Client  "AUTH TLS"
FTP response: Client  "234 Proceed with negotiation."
FTP command: Client  "PBSZ 0"
FTP response: Client  "200 PBSZ set to 0."
FTP command: Client  "PROT P"
FTP response: Client  "200 PROT now Private."
FTP command: Client  "USER user"
[user] FTP response: Client  "331 Please specify the password."
[user] FTP command: Client  "PASS <password>"
[user] OK LOGIN: Client "::ffff:0.0.0.0"
[user] FTP response: Client  "230 Login successful."
[user] FTP command: Client  "TYPE A"
[user] FTP response: Client  "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
[user] FTP command: Client  "PORT 46,4,20,119,230,43"
[user] FTP response: Client  "200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV."
[user] FTP command: Client  "LIST /httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8/8"
[user] FTP response: Client  "150 Here comes the directory listing."
[user] FTP response: Client  "226 Directory send OK."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3/9"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3/9/6"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8/8"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "CWD /httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8/8"
[user] FTP response: Client  "250 Directory successfully changed."
[user] FTP command: Client  "TYPE I"
[user] FTP response: Client  "200 Switching to Binary mode."
[user] FTP command: Client  "PORT 46,4,20,119,197,1"
[user] FTP response: Client  "200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV."
[user] FTP command: Client  "STOR /httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8/8/1636513356.png"
[user] FTP response: Client  "150 Ok to send data."
[user] FTP response: Client  "426 Failure reading network stream."
[user] FAIL UPLOAD: Client  "/httpdocs/2/3/9/6/7/8/8/1636513356.png", 40950 bytes, 290.83Kbyte/sec
[user] FTP command: Client  "QUIT"
[user] FTP response: Client  "221 Goodbye."
```

I don't know why, but it seems that passive mode command is not sended.
Target server is always the same and with the same script on another server but without php-fpm it works perfectly.

The server that execute the script is based on Debian 11, Apache 2.4 and php5.6-fpm; is there a possibility that the php execution is stopped before the transfer is finished?
I've disabled the firewall for testing but same error; also tryed on another server (with Deb 10 and php5.6-fpm) with same result :(

Fun fact, tryed with php7.4-fpm and php8.0-fpm on the same server and it works! So i think is a misconfiguration or a setting in php5.6... Any idea?

Comment: What does `ftp_pasv` return?

Comment: it returns true :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, after a whole night trying to understand, i'm writing the solution here so that can be useful to someone else: php5.6 don't support TLSv1.3 protocol, so i edited the `file /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and setted under the `system_default_sect` a max level for TLS, restarted php-fpm and... it worked!

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

For completeness, this directive does not affect Apache2, the TLSv1.3 protocol remains the same for web pages :)